# Does son of a realized sage become Brahman by birth?

Tags: brahman

Will the child of a realized soul become realized by birth automatically?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  No, not necessarily.  But it happens in some cases, like Vyasa's son Shuka.

Comment: reaized sages are born according to gotra only gotra can become the next in line like from the father to son and so on the lineage continues each of us have some form of lineage the rishis or sages are born of the lords mouth and from brahamas mana you cannot become a sage no matter how long you meditate or do deeds to change your janm line known as varna ashrama. here no one is discriminated but are given different duties to keep the world in balance

Comment: Highly likely. There are many instances of the sons of sages matching or, more often,  surpassing their learned fathers in realising Brahman.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Here http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/mundak/mun_3-2.html in Mantra 9, it is stated. Why do you say highly likely?

Comment: @asker What I said is highly likely is said to be a certainty by the mundaka. I could not say it with certainty due to the limitations of my knowledge. But if you already know the answer, what specifically were you hoping to gain out of asking it here?

Comment: @moonstar2001 I would like to know some examples in the modern time.

Comment: @Asker Then perhaps you should amend your question as such.

Comment: No, Son of realized soul doesn't become realized by birth. If the newly born person was realized, that soul wouldn't had taken birth at all because realized means one who is free from the cycle of birth and death. The one born, has to by his own self, attain realization/liberation. Avatars don't have to become free because they are already free.